# Call captureless with its type instead of its instance

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a code where I can have the type of the lambda, but not its instance, and I want to call it

I tried the following, and obviously, it does not work because `operator()` is not a static member function...

```cpp
#include <utility>

template<typename F, typename ...Args>
void call(F, Args&&... args) {
    &F::operator()(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    auto is_odd = [](auto x) {return x % 2 == 1;};
    call(is_odd, 5);
}
```

I tried also to convert it to a function pointer using :

```cpp
template<typename F, typename ...Args>
void call(F, Args&&... args) {
using return_type = decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args&&>()...));
    using ptr = return_type(*)(Args...);
    ptr f = static_cast<ptr>(&F::operator());
    f(std::forward<Args>()...);
}
```

But it does not work either. Is it possible to do something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you do have an instance. You pass it to your function, it's just that the parameter is not named. The fix is simple: name the parameter and use that:

```
template<typename F, typename ...Args>
void call(F f, Args&&... args) {
    f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
    
int main() {
    auto is_odd = [](auto x) {return x % 2 == 1;};
    call(is_odd, 5);
}
```

---

If for whatever reason you really are in a context where you don't have an instance then are out of luck unless you can use C++20. Before C++20 a lambda is not default constructible so you can't create an instance from it's type. With C++20 you can:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
void call(Args&&... args)
{
    F{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    auto is_odd = [](auto x) { return x % 2 == 1; };
    call<decltype(is_odd)>(5);
}
```

Comment: So with `F{}` you are default constructing a lambda given its type? Please bolov, can you please point me to a page on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) or elsewhere on this topic?

Comment: @Enrico it's [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). Nothing special about it except that you can't use it with lambda types before C++20.

Comment: I dont have The instance and I am not in cpp20 but cpp17 :+)

Comment: @AntoineMorrier you have only two options: redesign your code and store the instance somehow or switch to C++20

Comment: @AntoineMorrier there is a 3rd option: transform the lambda to function pointer and use that. That won't work however with generic lamdas like in your example.

Comment: da does not store anything and use it like `((F*)nullptr)(args...)`

Comment: @AntoineMorrier that is Undefined Behavior

Comment: @bolov, thanks for the link, but it sounds a bit special to me, in the sense that, now I understand it, it hinges on the fact that the _type_ of the lambda stores _the_ lambda (or maybe the appropriate term is _the closure_), so  we can default-construct it. We cannot default construct a `std::function` instead.